# Python regex : Difference in usage of re.sub, re.match & re.search for whitelisting

Tags: python, regex

All 3 statements below allow only alphabets, numbers, underscore & hyphen to pass through. Is there a difference between using `re.sub`, `re.match` & `re.search` below? i.e. is it possible to have a value for `str` where the execution paths of the `if statement below might be different for any of them?

```
str = 'some-random-string *&- '

if re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]', '',  str) == str:
    #do stuff

if re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', str):
    #do stuff

if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', str):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: look at the python docs for re.sub, re.match and re.search functions..

Comment: @Jerry & AvinashRaj Did you read the entire question to make out that I've read the docs & tried valid python code or just shoot out a snarky remark? Why the negativity? I have a valid question. The 3 statements arrive at the same result with different paths that have been constructed after reading the docs. Why not discuss the pros/cons rather than saying the obvious.

Comment: @click I read the entire question. It just didn't appear to me that you tried the code, because you're asking if there is a difference. I would have expected something along the lines of having tested a few test strings and all pass and that you wanted to get an assurance that they really work similarly. I know you cannot test every edge cases; but you could have put more than the one you have in your question. Is the question worth downvoting? I'd lean more towards yes, but it's borderline to me, so none from me here.

Comment: `It just didn't appear to me that you tried the code`. Really? That's odd. I thought maybe I was clear in asking that here's an example that works. Is it possible to break it with a different value of `str`. Brute force testing can be too costly for this and may or may-not catch the corner case.

Comment: @click You might say that I'm stating the obvious, but you can be surprised at the number of times I've seen people here putting something without testing it out. Second, there's no really pros or cons to be discussed. You are asking for whether they could behave differently, as in giving different results and not about performance (where there would be). To your next comment: Really? Yes really. It looks to me more like you took the code somewhere and are using it but don't understand it as well as you want to. I'm curious as to what 'brute force testing' could be. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You are wrong about me taking the code from somewhere. I've been testing this on an interpreter after going through the docs. Feel free to plug it into Google or Github search and get me a match. Brute force testing implies trying a large number of random combinations to find a corner case where they might behave differently as opposed to a carefully crafted test vector which can from someone more experienced in python/regex. Lastly, I'd say, making assumptions about the other person with a low reputation score is immature. Using an excuse that it happens often on SO is not nice.

Comment: @click That's fine and I'm glad you did. Your question just doesn't show it and that's what led me to those assumptions. Thank you for the elaboration and from that, I'm not sure how it can be costly? In any case, you sound like you did your homework but I just couldn't see it from your question. Lastly, I believe you are making assumptions too, because I never check the reputation of a user. I based myself only on the question. I was a user with less than 100 rep too once, believe it or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub` you get a new string and check it's not equal to what it was to detect if something was removed - that's not exactly performant.

Using `re.search` with the `^` to anchor the beginning of a match is the same as using `re.match`.

Using `re.match` is much more *explicit* of what you're trying to achieve, it *has* to match the pattern otherwise it's not valid - it can also shortcut early...

In short - stick with `re.match` for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer

Comment: Do you think that reversing the regex might make it short circuit faster? I'm thinking about `if not re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]', str):`

Comment: @Jerry we'll ignore that you're missing the `^` anchor, and it's effectively the same, but with a negated boolean operation on top... (which in Python is effectively another function call)

Comment: @JonClements Oh no! Using the `^` anchor would make this fail its purpose lol. And ok, if `not` is another function call, then I guess chances are it'll be anything but faster.

Comment: @Jerry yeah sorry... using `^` would be stupid... but yes, it would involve a `bool` call on the object returned from the search